# Cycles Baking Problem - Material all black. What might be wrong with my bake? Troubleshooting

Tags: texture-baking, baking

Cycles materials and the rendered image look good.
Then I baked the materials.
It worked fine for the wood. The baked image texture works well.
But for the metal, a procedural texture, the bake did not work at all.
I tried reset the normals, did not help.

Possibly the UV's are quite bad.  It was imported from a CAD program, and UV's were made automatically.  I'm new to UV's, not very good with them.  Maybe they need to be re-unwrapped?

Sorry I never did baking before, so I don't even know what *might* be wrong.
Maybe UV's?

How can I fix this problem, and in general, if baking does not work, what should we try to fix?

Rendered:
[image: Rendered]

Baked:
[image]

Normals:

[image]

Blend file here:  http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=43341

Comment: Bake is done along face normals. If you render (with the initial material) and place yourself just in top of the mesh : it is black. So the bake will be black too

Comment: Your problem is that you cannot bake glossy surfaces.  Baking will only work on non-reflective surfaces.

Comment: Thanks @lemon.  Was wondering which 'camera angle' it was baking to, if any.  Now I understand.  However if I look straight down on the top surface in render mode, it reflects the HDRI map that is lighting it.  It is not all black.  So not sure why the baking can't work?